# Who, if anyone, has standing to sue over improperly-run elections?

Tags: elections, georgia, standing

In [Wood v. Raffensperger](https://www.courtlistener.com/docket/18632787/wood-v-raffensperger/), Wood alleged that the Georgia 2020 general election was invalid due to the defendants conducting their election-related roles in an unconstitutional manner.

Like most lawsuits seeking to overturn the 2020 general election, the lawsuit failed for lack of standing due to the plaintiff having a generalized, rather than particular, grievance.  From [the motion denying the request for a temporary injunction](https://storage.courtlistener.com/recap/gov.uscourts.gand.283580/gov.uscourts.gand.283580.54.0_3.pdf):

> Starting  with  his  claim  asserted  under  the  Elections  and  Electors  Clause, Wood lacks standing as a matter of law. The law is clear: A generalized grievance regarding a state government’s failure to properly follow the Elections Clause of the Constitution does not confer standing on a private citizen.

Who, if anybody, would have had a particularized grievance here?  One of the candidates, perhaps?  Or, since the quote calls out "private citizens", some member of the government?

This is related to [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/58762/if-private-citizens-cannot-sue-when-the-grievance-is-common-to-all-citizens-who), but isn't a duplicate: I'm not asking about generalized grievances in general, but the specific allegations in *Wood v. Raffensperger*.